# Why might my Xcode be crashing (or at least displaying an error on launch)?

Tags: xcode

I am getting an error thrown when I launch my Xcode 3.2 all of a sudden:

Uncaught Exception:
*** -[NSCFArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object at objects[0]

I can click through the error and Xcode seems to launch properly. I removed and reinstalled Xcode to no avail, and yet cannot find a config or perference that might be the culprit.

I am running on 10.6.3 fwiw....

Has anyone else run into this problkem?

TIA!

Regards,

Steve O'Sullivan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I found !/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode.plist.

Quit Xcode, deleted that file and relaunched with no error....

::sigh::

Answer (score 0):

I don't know specifically what your error is, but you need to turn on the Xcode debugging option to catch Objective-C exceptions.